# Do I have to get a valid SSL certificate to make WebTranport server examples work?

Tags: ssl-certificate, self-signed-certificate, webtransport

I tried several WebTranport server examples, but failed to establish a webtransport connection with Chrome 111.

Server examples:

- https://github.com/wegylexy/webtransport/blob/main/ServerDemo/Program.cs
- https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Servers/Kestrel/samples/WebTransportSampleApp/Program.cs
- https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/webtransport/webtransport_server.py

Clients:

- https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/webtransport/client.html
- https://127.0.0.1/service-tests/webtransport-test/webtransport-test.html

The error was either

> net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.
> WebTransportError: Opening handshake failed.

or

> net::ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR.QUIC_TLS_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN (TLS handshake failure (ENCRYPTION_HANDSHAKE) 46: certificate unknown).
> WebTransportError: Opening handshake failed.

To make self-signed SSL certificate working, I tried using Chrome command line args

```
--user-data-dir=chromequicdata --origin-to-force-quic-on=localhost:4433 --ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list=Gi/HIwdiMcPZo2KBjnstF5kQdLI5bPrYJ8i3Vi6Ybck=
```

or passing server certificate hash as WebTransport constructor options

```js
  new WebTransport(url, {
    serverCertificateHashes: [
      {algortithm: 'sha-256', value: decodeBase64('Gi/HIwdiMcPZo2KBjnstF5kQdLI5bPrYJ8i3Vi6Ybck=')}
    ]
  });
```

Do I have to get a valid SSL certificate to make these server examples working?

Comment: When I use a valid SSL certificate (wildcard, ECC), without special configration like  command-line args or the serverCertificateHashes option, then the Python example webtransport_server.py is working, but other 2 examples are still not.

Answer (score 4):

It's not well documented, but `serverCertificateHashes` only works for EDCSA certificates valid for <14 days.

Here's how you [generate a valid certificate](https://github.com/kixelated/warp/blob/261d6927c156ab3efec8f59c75b6e337e7f4d107/cert/generate).

Answer (score 2):

For me the steps that are described in the [third server example](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/webtransport/webtransport_server.py)'s comments that you provided worked with Chrome 114 running the client example. They were:

> Here are step-by-step instructions on how to do that:
>
> 1. Generate a certificate and a private key:
>    openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout certificate.key 
>    -x509 -out certificate.pem -subj '/CN=Test Certificate' 
>    -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:localhost"
> 2. Compute the fingerprint of the certificate:
>    openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in certificate.pem |
>    openssl rsa -pubin -outform der |
>    openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | base64
>
>    The result should be a base64-encoded blob that looks like this:
>    "Gi/HIwdiMcPZo2KBjnstF5kQdLI5bPrYJ8i3Vi6Ybck="
> 3. Pass a flag to Chromium indicating what host and port should be allowed
>    to use the self-signed certificate.  For instance, if the host is
>    localhost, and the port is 4433, the flag would be:
>    --origin-to-force-quic-on=localhost:4433
> 4. Pass a flag to Chromium indicating which certificate needs to be trusted.
>    For the example above, that flag would be:
>    --ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list=Gi/HIwdiMcPZo2KBjnstF5kQdLI5bPrYJ8i3Vi6Ybck=

Problems I ran into:

- not using the correct fingerprint at the ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list flag or the correct cert file if i had many in one folder or the correct port number on the client's side
- using the wrong tag at the cert and key file generation. Because if you want to use this method with a simple IP address, not a hostname, you should use:

  - -addext "subjectAltName = IP.1:..."
- using an older version of Chrome was also a problem, so you should try to update to 114

These are really general solutions, but they might help you.